# Creating an advanced searchform based on select boxes

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

I am trying to create a WordPress website where a user can post a car that he is trying to sell with contact details for it. I have most of the things figured out about how this website will work. My only problem is creating a search form for it.

I would like the search form to contain two `<select>` boxes.  The first one should have a list of all the cars and the second one a list of all the models. When the user selects a car from the first box, the second box should dynamically generate a list of model cars. I do not know if this is even possible in WordPress. I could not find any resources about this.

Is there any way to achieve this? I am not looking for exact code but some directions on this if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing your car and models as custom taxonomies, then this plugin will probably help you out.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/